# Plotly: How to change the title of the colorbar using bx.bar?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I can't figure out how to change the title of the color-legend in plotly. (Example Image, blue circle)

[image: Link to the example image]

Comment: https://plotly.com/python/figure-labels/

maybe it can help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `px.bar` with settings that produce a colorbar, use:

```
fig.layout.coloraxis.colorbar.title = 'another title'
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
data = px.data.gapminder()

data_canada = data[data.country == 'Canada']
fig = px.bar(data_canada, x='year', y='pop',
             hover_data=['lifeExp', 'gdpPercap'], color='lifeExp',
             labels={'pop':'population of Canada'}, height=400)

fig.layout.coloraxis.colorbar.title = 'another title'

fig.show()
```

Comment: This doesnt work with plotly express (TypeError: bar() got an unexpected keyword argument 'colorbar'), but I think I have to use plotly.graph_objects :/

Anyway, Thank you :)

Comment: @mariusEBR You did not specify that you're using plotly express. Next time, please include a reproducible code snippet to make it easier to get precise answers. Anyway, check out my new suggestion.

Comment: Yes I will. Thank you for your answer. Finally it works

Comment: As of Feb 2023, this works with Plotly Express

Answer (score 1):

You can update the layout

```
fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar_title_text = 'Colorbar Title')
```

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69909540/plotly-express-update-the-colorbar-title).