# Plotly Express: Update the colorbar title

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'm using plotly Express density_heatmap and i'm trying to update manually the name of the legend (here the color continuous scale). I tried with labels, update_layout but it looks like i can't remove the **'sum of'** or **'count'** etc from the legend.
Here i modified example from plotly:

```
import plotly.express as px
dft = px.data.iris()
figt = px.density_heatmap(dft, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", z='sepal_length',
                         labels=dict(z='sepal_length'))
figt.show()
```

[image]

Is there a way to remove this **sum of**?
Thanks in andvance

Comment: try this: `figt.layout['coloraxis']['colorbar']['title']['text'] = 'Another title'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotly: How to change the title of the colorbar using bx.bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63968285/plotly-how-to-change-the-title-of-the-colorbar-using-bx-bar)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
figt.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar_title_text = 'your title')
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
dft = px.data.iris()
figt = px.density_heatmap(dft, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", z='sepal_length',
                         labels=dict(z='sepal_length'))

figt.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar_title_text = 'your title')
figt.show()
```